# Random Forest on ordinal dependent variable

Tags: random-forest, ordinal-data

I have a dataset with ~1000 obs and 10 categorical predictors. My dependent variable is ordinal and Poisson distributed. Can someone guide me on what technique to use for this case?
I have tried using random forest with trees having non-parametric assumptions, treating the dependent as a continuous variable. For scoring I round off the predicted value to nearest integer,which is giving me better results than treating it as a classification problem. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: if you are using mean/sum squared error as a loss function, have you tried using `-log poisson probability(training value | classifier output)` instead as loss function (for a regression problem) ?

Comment: How does an ordinal poisson distribution look like? do you mean discrete? Maybe add a plot of your dependent variable distribution. If you reduce you ordinal or discrete variable to categories, your're discarding the information that 1 is closer to 2 than 4 etc. The RF regression loss function is derived from change of sum of squares. From a machine learning perspective you should choose a transformation which gives the best cross validated performance. Holzner's suggestions seem wise